# Use response from previous resolve object

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-ui-router

I have an angularjs route with a resolve object with multiple properties like so:

```
.state('user', {
                url: '/user/signup',
                controller: 'CreateAccountCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'createaccount.tpl.html',
                resolve: {
                    practice: {
                        // Returns a promise
                    },
                    someOtherFunction: {
                        // Returns a promise, needs resolved object from practice
                    },
                }
            })
```

The problem is that I need the result from one of the resolves to process the other resolve. How can I implement this? Obviously I can just put all the http calls in one function and build a custom object but I am wondering if there's a more idiomatic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn both properties of the `resolve` method into functions and pass one method by name to the other as an argument.

```
.state('user', {
  url: '/user/signup',
  controller: 'CreateAccountCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'createaccount.tpl.html',
  resolve: {
    practice: function() {
        // Returns a promise
    },
    someOtherFunction: function(practice) {
        // Returns a promise, needs resolved object from practice
    }
  }
})
```

Also, [this blog post](http://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-resolve-application-wide-resources-centrally-in-angularjs-with-ui-router/) is a great resource for using Angular UI Router. I learned this approach there.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to return the `resolve` object:

```
...
resolve: (function () {
    var practicePromise;
    var someOtherPromise;

    /* initialize the variables whichever way you want*/

    return { /* this is the actual "resolve" object*/

        practice: practicePromise,
        someOther: someOtherPromise
    };
} ()),
...
```